# Python 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, traceback

i created this program which will replace a sentence with the words in its position and saves them as a separate file. However when i run it i get this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File , line 12, in 
        Positions = list2.index(word)

here is the code:

```
UserSentence = input("enter sentence:").lower()
words = UserSentence
words = words.split()
number = 0
list1 = []
list2 = " "

for Position in words:
    if Position not in list1:
        list1.append(Position)
for word in words:
        Positions = list2.index(word)
        list2+=str(Positions+int("1"))
        list2 +=("")
list1str += ";".join(list1)

file = open ("myfile.txt","w")
file.write(sentence)
file.write(list1str)
file.write(list2)
file = open ("myfile.txt", "r")
print (file.read())
file.close()
```

could someone explain me what mistake i made in my code?

Comment: `words = words.split` should be `words = words.split()`.

Comment: thank you but now it gices me a traceback error on the line Positions = list2.index(word)
ValueError: substring not found why is it so?

Comment: During the first iteration of `for word in words`, `list2` only contains a space, so `list2.index(word)` will fail unless `word` is also just a space. But it's a word, not a space. Incidentally, `list2` is not a list, so you should not call it a list.

Comment: how can i make word just a space?

Comment: Easy: `word = " "`. But why would you want to do that? It will make the error go away, but it won't make your program work properly.

Comment: Alright i will need to rewrite the coee i think. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
UserSentence = input("enter sentence:").lower()
words = UserSentence
words = words.split() # actually call the function
```

Without using the parentheses, you are actually assigning the method `.split` to the variable `words`, then trying to iterate over it, giving you the error.

Answer (score 0):

You set `words = words.split`, but you aren't actually calling the method, so instead you are trying to iterate over the reference to that function. Call the method instead with `words = words.split()`